# <div> background hide when I use "float: left" on <li> - menu

Tags: css, html, menu

See code, below code is my question ;).

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Domov</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">O nás</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Služby</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background: #363b40;
}

.header ul li {
    float: left;
}

.header a {
    color: #a3a7a6;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

My question is why DIV background hide when I add "float: left" to .header ul li. Any solution please?

Comment: @Danny jan reimers has the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason this is occurring is because the `ul` is collapsing, as it doesn't have any defined dimensions. When you float the children elements, it takes them out of the flow of the document. The same thing happens when you set their position to absolute.

You have a few options..

Set `overflow:hidden` on the parent, forcing it to contain the children.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/EYT2G/)

```
.header ul {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

...or setting a defined height on the `ul`.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/grBGX/)

```
.header ul {
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but don't you have any other solution without using height on ul ?

Comment: @Danny `overflow:hidden` see the above example.. don't use a clearfix.

Comment: Josh - I'm so sorry, I would rather go to eye doctor ! :D

Answer (score 1):

add the class `clearfix` to `header` and the following code to your css

```
.clearfix:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.clearfix {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

`