# How to center a text while still being aligned to the left/right?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered vertical list..

```
 <div>
 <ul>
 <li>home</li>
 <li>portfolio</li>
 <li>about</li>
 <li>contact</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

css:

```
 div {
 width: 600px;
 }
 ul {
 text-align: center;
 }
```

What I really want is the list to be text aligned left, while the ul is still horizontally in the center. is there a way to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this to center dynamically generated content of varying widths:

```
div { text-align: center; }

ul { display: inline-block; }

li { text-align: left; }
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/6Z6Rr/)

Alternatively, you can set a defined width on the parent, and use `margin:0px auto`, assuming it is a `block` level element.

```
ul {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5MyFu/)

Comment: I see, thanks. ok just to be sure on the second method, would it be safe to set a specific width for the ul? text is not dynamic, but wouldn't get messy in some cases? like maybe when the page is zoomed or something?

Comment: @MagdiGamal It would be safer to set the width on the `ul` as opposed to the parent `div`.. either would technically work, however if the `ul` doesn't have defined dimensions, it will collapse on its children elements in a few instances... **[related to this question I answered a few days ago..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19775657/div-background-hide-when-i-use-float-left-on-li-menu/19775718#19775718)**

Comment: @MagdiGamal And just so you know.. you got 4 answer on your **[other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19799714/why-is-the-selector-not-working-here/19799799#19799799)**.